# Webcam from notebook show grey screen using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, webcam-capture

This is my code, when I run my program, the screen don't show anything.
I'm using opencv3.1 and visual studio 2017.

```
    cvNamedWindow("Live",1);
    cvMoveWindow("Live", 85, 60);
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
if(capture)
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            if (!cvGrabFrame(capture))
                break;
            IplImage* image = cvRetrieveFrame(capture);
            cvShowImage("Live", image);
            if (cvWaitKey(10) >= 0){
                break;}
        }
        cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
        cvDestroyWindow("Live");
    }
```

Comment: Is it C or C++? please add a tag

Comment: Don't use **obsolete** C API!!!

Comment: I confuse a bit because my friend can run this code but I can't.